# Handling Unpublished page in Facebook add_to_page_dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am adding my Facebook application to Facebook Fan pages through the Facebook Javascript [add_to_page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) dialog. Every thing is working Fine, only the problem with unpublished Facebook pages.

I am retrieving the Facebook pages IDs of all the pages to which the app is added. If a person add it to such a FB page which is unpublished, I can't get the Page ID and app is still added to the Facebook page. I want to prevent the app to add to the unpublished page in case.

The Facebook developer documentation provides no help regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the pages a user administers will appear in the dialog - there's no way to prevent an unpublished or otherwise restricted page from being selected - if you have `manage_pages` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from the user you can act as all of their pages, including the unpublished pages.

If you don't, and need to know which page your app is being loaded on, the signed_request sent to your app when the tab is loaded will include the page ID

Comment: Then how i will be able to delete my app from that page without requiring any extended permissions.

Comment: You won't, why would you need to? Why not just show no content if it's the 'wrong' page ID in the signed request?

Comment: It can be, but i was in search of best possible solution , less user managing and admin handling feature, but unfortunate. BTW Thank you very much

Comment: You can't prevent people adding your app by calling the dialog manually, using the API, etc, so there are other reasons not to rely solely on the response from the dialog to know which pages you need to support